# Accessing Attributes

Tags: objective-c

I am new to programming and objective C, sorry I have to ask this basic question. I can not figure out the lines of code below. Why do I need to use & sign for the range when assess attributes? but not use it when I call the attribute again? is it because the first one is a setter and second one is getter?

Thanks for your advises in advances!

```
-(NSAttributedString*)characterWithAttribute: (NSString*)attributeName{
    NSMutableAttributedString* characters = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];

    int index = 0;

    while(index < [self.textToAnalyze length]){

        NSRange range;

        id value = [self.textToAnalyze attribute:attributeName atIndex:index effectiveRange:&range];

        if(value){

            [characters appendAttributedString:[self.textToAnalyze attributedSubstringFromRange:range]];
            index = (int)range.location + (int)range.length;
        }
        else{
            index++;
        }
    }

    return characters;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it because the first one is a setter and second one is getter?

Basically, yes.  The ampersand specifies the address of the variable rather than the value.  When the called routine has an address, it can assign a value to it for you to use when it returns.  If the called routine only had a value, it wouldn't be able to replace it in any way that was accessible to the caller.

Here's a link that might give you more in-depth details:
https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference